# React-native run-android - uses-sdk:minSdkVersion cannot be smaller error

Tags: react-native

### Heading

Running command `react-native run-android` the build fails exactly at the same location and produces me the following `error` :

```
:app:processDebugManifest
C:\Users\me\ReactApp\wats\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-8:12 Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [wats:react-native-watson:unspecified] C:\Users\me\ReactApp\wats\node_modules\react-native-watson\android\build\intermediates\bundles\default\AndroidManifest.xml
        Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.reactlibrary" to force usage

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
:app:processDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I know what this error should suppose to mean. The issue is that the referenced AndroidManifest declares the minSdkVersion to be 19 already:
`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26"
     />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

`

It clearly seems to be some kind of cache issue. The most annoying is that even if I create a completely new Native React project and install the needed packages and try to run it, then I get the same error (even if I have explicitly made sure that all those values in the Manifest are correct). 
I have tried commands `npm clear cache --force` which doesn't work; also, it seems that `react-native run-android --reset-cache` doesn't work (found one RN ticket about it, but it seems it has never been fixed); tried `gradlew clean` command under android studio, but that didn't have any effect.

Any ideas what to try?

Answer (score 5):

Opened React Native project in Android Studio, and tried to compile the project from there. The process failed as well, but the error message in Android Studio was a bit more specific. From the React Native error message I got an impression that the issue laid with the `AndroidManifest` file, but actually the issue was inside `build.gradle` file, which indeed defined `minSdkVersion` to be 16. After updating this value the problem got solved.